# How to set priority of Rails ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

How to set priority of Rails ActionMailer?

```
UserMailer.test.deliver_later
```

I use DelayedJob to queue_adapter.

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 6:

```rb
# config/initializers/set_mail_delivery_job_priority.rb
ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob.priority = 0
```

References:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.0/activejob/lib/active_job/core.rb#L85
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.0/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_priority.rb#L32

Answer (score 0):

Aren't all mails sent on the "mailers" queue? If so, you can simply tell DJ the priority for said queue:

`(bundle exec) sidekiq ... -q mailers,2 ...`